# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 with ajax on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, asp.net-ajax, httpmodule

```
function Loadtodo(s) {
          $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              async: true,
              url: "Home.aspx/LoadTodo",
              data: "{InvitaionID:" + s + "}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (response) {
                  count = response.d.length;
                  if(count!=0)
                  count = response.d[0].temp;
                  for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {
                      if (response.d[i].Ischecked == 'false') {
                          $('.todo-card').prepend('<div class="todo-task"> ' +
          '<input type="checkbox" id=' + response.d[i].checkboxid + ' /> ' +
          '<label for=' + response.d[i].checkboxid + '>' + response.d[i].todoitem + ' <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> ' +
          '</label> </div> ');
                      }

                      else {
                          $('.todo-card').prepend('<div class="todo-task"> ' +
          '<input type="checkbox" id=' + response.d[i].checkboxid + ' checked="yes" /> ' +
          '<label for=' + response.d[i].checkboxid + '>' + response.d[i].todoitem + ' <span class="todo-remove mdi-action-delete"></span> ' +
          '</label> </div> ');

                      }

                  }

              },
              failure: function (response) {
                  //alert(response.d);
              },
              error: function (response) {

              }
          });

      }
```

This is my ajax code. Which i call on jquery document load. I hosted this application on the IIS server. Getting error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).
But it working fine when i run the application on the visual studio development server

Comment: Have you double checked the url it generates for POST request? There could be some issue with the id you're sending.

Comment: My code working well on VS development server. Failing in IIS

Comment: Are you using SQLLocalDB ? Have you tried adding a try/catch block and sending the error message back?

Comment: Just to clarify; you've selected both ASP.NET and Classic ASP tags.  Which is it?

Comment: Where to select the classic asp tags?

Comment: If you edit your post and look at the bottom where you entered the tags originally and remove those that aren't required. Presently you have [tag:asp.net], [tag:asp-classic], [tag:iis-7], [tag:asp.net-ajax] and [tag:httpmodule]. Make sure you've got the ones you need because you're more likely to get your question answered correctly.

Comment: I have the same problem. In my case the error is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500", fired when the javascript tries to load a .wsem video file from the server...